Unable to Login to HPSM
We have HPSM version 9.6 and we are currently facing an issue related to Login. We have verified our LDAP setting but couldn't understand why the following error message is coming - "Invalid login name/password. Please try again."
We have performed the following checks as HPSM is connected to our enterprise AD:

Connectivity of the LDAP server from the Application Server.
We verified if the connectivity of Database Server.
We also verified that we are running a compatible version of Java(Java SE 8u333) and Apache Tomcat (8.5)
We also tried Log in using the HPSM client software with the HPSM User ID, but it also gave the same error message.
Needless to mention the defaulf HPSM Services(sm960service) are running normally.

Also we did check the SM.log file where we could see some error logs as follows:

2024-06-03 09:35:39,233 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8016-exec-4] [-4053ed7d5c] [com.hp.ov.cwc.web.ConfigReader] Name [alternateTheme] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [alternateTheme].
2024-06-03 09:35:39,249 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8016-exec-4] [-4053ed7d5c] [com.hp.ov.web.csrf.CSRFTokenManager] ---random algorithm: SHA1PRNG
2024-06-03 09:35:40,014 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8016-exec-4] [upn-4053ed7d5c] [com.hp.ov.cwc.web.bean.FrameworkBean] Missing resource: licenseLogos
2024-06-03 09:35:40,030 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8016-exec-4] [upn-4053ed7d5c] [com.hp.ov.sm.client.webtier.SCLogging] SOAP connection disconnected from server at http://server-name:13083/SM/ui

HPSM UI Error Screenshot
Can any one help?
